# Angular4 Firebase function 'firebase deploy' error "functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code4294963238"

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-functions

After writing my first firebase function in Typescripts, I wanted to deploy the function but this error poped up of no where. When i entered command `firebase deploy`

```
i  deploying firestore, functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17035
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program                             
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--prefix" 
"$RESOURCE_DIR" "run" "lint"
npm ERR! node v6.11.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path F:\Projects\Angular 
Projects\<project_derectory>\$RESOURCE_DIR\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Projects\Angular 
Projects\<project_derectory>\$RESOURCE_DIR\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Projects\Angular 
Projects\<project_derectory>\$RESOURCE_DIR\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     F:\Projects\Angular Projects\<project_derectory>\npm-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code4294963238
```

I have followed steps as [this medium blog tutorial](https://medium.com/netscape/firebase-cloud-functions-with-typescript-and-webpack-7781c882a05b)

Comment: That blog is old.  If you want to write Cloud Functions with TypeScript, you should get the latest Firebase CLI, which has native support for TS.  https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/01/why-you-should-use-typescript-for.html

Answer (score 0):

same here, you may try JavaScript. i think they have problem with typescript

from comment below for people to get the solution

`Please edit the json file "firebase.json" in your firebase functions directory. change the "$RESOURCE_DIR" to "functions"`

Comment: Please edit the json file "firebase.json" in your firebase functions directory. change the "$RESOURCE_DIR" to "functions"

Comment: Problem still there even after changing to javascript and firebase.json file already has source set to functions

Comment: I can see you are using "Nodejs v6.11.5" could you please try to update to v6.12.3.Please notice it is just trail